# call action form json type block magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to call action method within the

```
{{block type="multibanners/multibanners" category_id="9" name="multibanners" alias="multibanners" template="multibanners/multibanners.phtml"}}.
```

OR

alternate for action in the `json type block` ?

Thanks

Comment: I want to pass variable from the block so that i can get the value of variable in phtml or blocks in my custom module.I try $this->getData("category_id") method and $this->getCategoryId() for this , but nothing happen.Hope you got my point

Comment: What is the difference between this question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245880/how-to-pass-parameter-with-block-form-contents-from-cms-pages-in-magento

Comment: On that question i try how i can pass variable using block while here i want to know alternate for action method in json block type.

Comment: Are you sure you have setup your module code correctly? Is You block actually being loaded at all?

Comment: yes my code is running perfect with xml block, but when i try to use static  blocks {{block}} it will not work.Infact i have no idea how to set parameters with this block type ?