# how product images sizes effect bandwith and speed of site

Tags: image, magento, bandwidth, pagespeed

we uploaded product images with 400 kb,

when uploading the images, will it use bandwidth of 400 kb or will it take the bandwidth of

what product image size we gave in base and thumbinal width and how it works for zooming .

when the image is zooming, will it take 400 kb bandwidth or only the size of zooming the we set.

please guide me about this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use Firebug in Firefox, when you hover over the image src link in the img tag, it'll tell you what size image is being used. Magento does resize images in some cases so this will tell you if the image was resized. CSS size settings have no impact on the image file size.

Comment: hi, what about zooming images....

Comment: I'm guessing you mean product images where you get a thumbnail and then get a zoom when you hover your cursor over it? The thumbnail should be a small image, and the zoomed image the larger full size. Ideally the zoomed image should only be fetched if/when it's used.

Comment: ya @PedroKTFC you are right, on the right bottom of the product view page, there is a "+"image if you click on that "+" image,
than it will show the real product image size, i want to reduce that product image size....

Comment: The simplest way is to resize your images before uploading them. Alternatively, you could use Magento's image resizing mechanism to ensure images are limited in size. See my answer here to an unrelated question for pointers to how you might use the mechanism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245880/how-to-pass-parameter-with-block-form-contents-from-cms-pages-in-magento/17741001#17741001 although there are probably other better ways.

Comment: but we already added some 200 images.....